# Live wallpaper swiper gestures

Tags: android, eclipse, live-wallpaper, gesture-recognition, swipe-gesture

I am finishing my live wallpaper and it is working well apart from performance issues, for now I applied a script that helps for swipe gestures and touch detection.

```
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) 

                {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager  
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                    if (prefs.getBoolean("Touch_lock_key",true))
                    {  
                             switch (touchevent.getAction())
                             {
                                    // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
                                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                                     {
                                         x1 = touchevent.getX();
                                         y1 = touchevent.getY();
                                         break;
                                    }
                                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                                     {
                                         x2 = touchevent.getX();
                                         y2 = touchevent.getY(); 

                                         //right swipe

                                         if (x1-x2< 0 ) 
                                         {

                                            try {

                                                mImagesArrayIndex++;
                                                Thread.sleep(SeekBarPreference1.mCurrentValue1);
                                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                          }

                                         // left swipe
                                         if (x1-x2>0 )
                                         {
                                             try {

                                                    mImagesArrayIndex--;
                                                    Thread.sleep(SeekBarPreference1.mCurrentValue1);
                                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                         }


                                         break;
                                     }
                             }
                             return;
                }

                }
```

As you can see I utilize .getaction function to manage touch and swipe gestures. Its working but not as I expected. The problems are:

1. ultra sensitive to the touch and becomes annoying when using this live wallpaper.
2. doesn't follow left-right swipes properly.
3. left-right swipes doesn't stop when finger swipe stops across the screen.

What I want:

1. any other swipe gesture manager script that might help with my case (live wallpaper - no activity is involved here)
2. smooth swipe effect like we see on any live wallpapers out there, take the titanfall LW as a sample.

Here's a video that might help you understand the situation:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B44QwXQHh5irOGlXNDNpOThYb3c/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, this code works the same as the previous one I just added some modifications concerning precision and touch tracking..

```
@Override  

    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {

            //when user touches the screen  
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
            {  
                //reset deltaX and deltaY  
                deltaX=0;

                //get initial positions  
                initialX = event.getRawX();  
                initialY = event.getRawY();  
            }  

            //swipe gestures tracking
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)    
            {    
                deltaX = event.getRawX() - initialX;    
                deltaY = event.getRawY() - initialY;      

                if(deltaY < 0)   
                {    
                    //Actions UP
                }   
                else   
                {    
                    //Actions DOWN
                }   

                if(deltaX < 0)   
                {   
                     initialX = event.getRawX(); 
                    // actions RIGHT
                    }

                }  

                else  
                { 
                    initialX = event.getRawX();   
                    // actions LEFT
                        }
                }   


                return;  


    }  
    }
```

---

here's a result:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B44QwXQHh5irZUtEM3ZZQmRHcFk/view?usp=sharing

---

I hope someone finds this helpful &... HAPPY CODING !

Answer (score 1):

onTouch() is called several times for any given gesture, so you're incrementing much more than you want to. A start would be to use GestureDetector and GestureDetector.SimpleGestureListener.

Sic:

```
private GestureDetector mDetector
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(...) {
    ...
    mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, mGestureListener);
    setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());
    ...
}
...
private class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
...
private GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener
        = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        ...
    }
    // the IDE will create all these methods for you
    //EDIT: I forgot SimpleOnGestureListener isn't abstract, so it won't do this. OnGestureListener is, so the IDE will. 
};
```

The basic sequence of a swipe looks like this

```
onDown()
onScroll()
onScroll()
....
onScroll()
onFling()
```

So if you really want to handle the gesture yourself, the events you're looking for are onDown and on Fling (you could do this with onTouch ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP, but SimpleOnGestureListener gives you more functions).

But I would really suggest looking into a view that already handles all this for you, like ViewPager